# Javascript, textarea, best way to detect line been changed

Tags: javascript, textarea, onchange, textinput

I'm trying to make something like adding WYSIWYG editing sigins on images.

So, I got textarea for text.  I generate (in real time) `<svg>` text there. Text can be inside `<svg><rect>`. On every line break its a new line and new `<rect>`. I set rect size (witdth, height) depends on what returns `text.getBBox()` function, storing data about each rect sizes in some array by index.

Now, if I change some text in middle line, i want to change size of rectangle where this text is placed.

How should i detect, which line has been changed by it size? 
Ofc I can store old textarea data, compare with changed data every time on textinput, find changed line etc but seems like its a bad solution

**UPD**:

I assume there is workaround to redraw ALL text I got in `<textarea>`, line by line, every time it changes, but it looks like not good solution too